# docker-machine direct install on Ubuntu with curl getting permission denied with sudo

Tags: ubuntu, docker-machine, ubuntu-16.04

The instructions provided for installing docker-machine on Linux are way off for Ubuntu.

These are the incorrect instructions (found [here](https://docs.docker.com/machine/install-machine/#installing-machine-directly)):

```
$ curl -L https://github.com/docker/machine/releases/download/v0.7.0/docker-machine-`uname -s`-`uname -m` > /usr/local/bin/docker-machine && \
$ chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-machine
```

- You will have all kinds of permission denied errors while using `sudo`.
- Once you hack your way around the sudo permission problems you will find your `docker-machine` file is empty after the install.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After a few hours of hacking around I found this is what is needed for installing docker-machine on Ubuntu (at least for the version I am running Lubuntu (16.04 LTS / Xenial Xerus):

```
$ sudo wget -L https://github.com/docker/machine/releases/download/v0.8.0-rc1/docker-machine-`uname -s`-`uname -m`
$ sudo mv docker-machine-`uname -s`-`uname -m` /usr/local/bin/docker-machine
$ sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-machine
```

To test it has installed:

```
$ docker-machine version
```

Comment: nice! but second line should be `sudo mv docker-machine-\`uname -s\`-\`uname -m\` /usr/local/bin/docker-machine`, shouldn't it? anyway thanks for help, saved my time!

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem today, in a debian machine. I'm updated with the command I used since `docker-machine` is now `docker-compose`

`` wget -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.13.0/docker-compose-`uname -s`-`uname -m`
sudo mv ./docker-compose-`uname -s`-`uname -m` /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose ``